# Is there a way to style the blue focus ring on text links with CSS?

Tags: html, css, focus, styling

I'm having some issues trying to style the `:focus` state for text links in my SCSS design system, to ensure accessibility on keyboard navigation but also to make it look a bit nicer than the stock box outline.

I've managed to get it working cross-browser for text fields and buttons by using `outline:none;` and replacing it visually with `box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px $color`. I have to do this because Safari's focus outline doesn't follow `border-radius`.

Here's how it looks for form fields:
[three text fields, the first of which has a custom focus state border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LElHx.png)

But for text, it still has the blue outline:
[snippet of text with visited links, one has focus but still has a blue outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxxbW.png)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  color: #0000ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p {
  color: #3b3b3b;
  font-family: system-ui;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

a:focus-visible {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: white;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #0000ff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

a:visited:focus-visible {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px purple;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p>Here is some text. <a href="#">Here's one link.</a> And here is some other text in between. And here is another link. <a href="#">Another link.</a></p>
```

[Here's a CodePen demo.](https://codepen.io/ajkandy/pen/ExLKvqa)

As you can see, when you use tabs or keyboard navigation, when a visited link has `:focus`, it gets the correct background and text color, but still has a blue focus border, and I can't seem to get rid of it.

Using the Inspector, I can't see any other styles that are overriding it. It does follow the `border-radius`, so I'm just kind of confused as to where it's coming from.

CSS is supposed to let you stack basic selectors like `:visited` and `:focus-visible`, right?

For reference, this isn't exclusive to Safari, it happens in Chrome and Firefox as well, so it does seem to be CSS-related.

Comment: As a test, I just changed `outline:none;` to `outline: 1px solid $color-text-link-visited;` and it doesn't really change it, there's still a blue fringe visible.

Comment: Note that the selector `:focus-visible` is only available in modern browsers since year 2021

Comment: Isn't an input in your image @A.J.Kandy? Please add all the relevant code to make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @yousoumar Thanks, updated. There was an image for the text but it was at the end of the question, so maybe it was easy to miss. Moved it to the top next to the other one.

Comment: @bron Do you think it would work with simple `:focus`? I'll give it a try. (EDIT: It doesn't.)